# start server inside screen with shell file

Tags: command-line, 18.04, ssh, minecraft

I have a Minecraft server that I start over ssh. I use screen so it keeps running

Spigot allows you to set a start script so that if the server stops it can start again automatically.

I currently have the following code for my spigot start command (this is inside a shell file that spigot runs)

```
#!/bin/sh
screen -s minecraft -x ~/path/to/server/start.sh
```

then in my `start.sh` file I have the following

```
#!/bin/sh
java -Xmx1500m -jar server.jar -nogui
```

before I started with the restart I would ssh into the computer, start screen then run the `start.sh` file. But now I need a file that will start screen and run the `start.sh` file

How do I do this?

Comment: You don't need to use `screen` or scripts at all. Minecraft Server runs quite happily as a systemd service, with all the systemd settings, benefits, and options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-X            Execute <cmd> as a screen command in the specified session.
-x            Attach to a not detached screen. (Multi display mode).
```

what i did was see the `-X` flag and made 2 mistakes
the first was to use lowercase `x` not an uppercase `X`

the second was that you don't need the `-X` flag, and you can just use

```
screen -s minecraft ~/path/to/the/start.sh
```

and give the command or file as an argument without the flag